# When extruding, why can't I extrude any faces or edges because I am stuck on extruding vertices?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to extrude faces but every time I click on a face, it changes to vertices

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the object you want to edit by right-clicking it.
2. Tab into Edit mode.
3. Select the vertices, edges, or faces you want to extrude.
   Use any of the selection methods listed in the previous section.
4. Extrude your selection in one of several ways:

- Use the E hotkey.
- Left-click Add→Extrude Region in the Tools tab of the Tool Shelf.
- Choose Mesh→Extrude→Extrude Region from the menu in the 3D View’s
  header.

After you extrude your selection, Blender automatically puts you into grab mode on the newly extruded parts.

[image: Extrude]